# Check textarea is empty and checkbox was selected at least one when submit using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I develop an app using codigniter. In view, I have a form like this :

```
<div class="box-content">   
<?php
$properties = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => 'myForm');
echo form_open("control_request/userRequest", $properties);
?>

<fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Jenis Request :</label>
        <div class="controls" id="chekboxes">
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" > Login </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Printer" value="Printer"> Printer </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Monitor" value="Monitor"> Monitor</label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Computer" value="Computer"> Computer</label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Network" value="Network"> Network</label>
            <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Lain-lain" value="Lain-lain" > Lain-lain</label>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="control-group hidden-phone">
        <label class="control-label" for="Complaint" Complaint : </label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="cleditor" name="Complaint" id="Complaint" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit"  >Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Now, I create some javascript using jquery to validate, if the checkbox and textarea was qualify before submit. Here is the logic of jquery :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function(e){

               if (chekbox not selected at least one ) {
                      <p> Please choose at least one </p>
                   }
               if textbox is empty {
                   <p> Pleaser fill the textbox </p>
                 }
               if (all qualified)
                  submit

            });
    </script>
```

I just wanna check all of the element is qualified before submitting. But if not qualified, there will be a error message like this

```
()Checkbox1 ()Checkbox2 ()Checkbox3  ()Checkbox 4    <p>Please select one</p>

<textarea></textarea>   <p>Please describe your complaint</p>
```

I am using jquery 1.9.1 , I will keep learn, and for the help thank you so much..
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Fadly_Dzil_Massere/pfmufmty/)

Comment: Sorry, not clear what you are asking. Do you want to validate if textarea is having some text and at least one checkbox is selected? Unable to get what did you mean by - "the script above make my textarea is disabled". Please elaborate.

Comment: Can you make jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Above code doen not have any relationship with your textarea , so how does it get disabled ? do you have another validation codes , please post them

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear ..but it may help you what do you need

```
$("textarea:empty").length == 0 // text area empty
$(".checkbox [type=checkbox]:checked").length >= 1 // at least one is selected
```

Answer (score -1):

1. If you need to make the textarea mandatory, use `requierd`
   attribute. The jQuery validate plugin that you have used will do the
   rest of the trick for validation.
2. For checking if at least one of the checkboxes is selected, you can
   add one rule for checkboxes:

   ```
   rules: {
           'request[]': {
               required: true,
               minlength:2
            }
   },
   ```

   OR

   You can add a custom rule:

   ```
   $.validator.addMethod("request[]", function(value, elem, param) {
       if($(".request[]:checked").length > 0){
          return true;
      }else {
          return false;
      }
   },"You must select at least one checkbox to continue");
   ```